# parse large csv file on php

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I have a csv file, which is tab delimited. Inside the cells have used a semicolon as a separator between values. Whether php means to process the file and get to the exit to the right of each line array of values.

here is my code:

```
$handle = fopen($name_csv, "r");
            $data_import = array();
            if(empty($handle) === false) {
                while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
                    foreach( $data as $key => $val ) {

                        $data[$key] = trim( $data[$key] );
                        $data[$key] = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $data[$key]);
                        $data[$key] = str_replace('""', '"', $data[$key]);
                        $data[$key] = preg_replace("/^\"(.*)\"$/sim", "$1", $data[$key]);

                    }
                    $data_import[] = $data;
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
```

output array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test;test;test;"test value; test value";test
        )
```

The file size 300 MB.

original csv:

```
test;test;test;"test value; test value";test
test;test;test;"test value; test value";test
test;test;test;"test value; test value";test
test;test;test;"test value; test value";test
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Something doesn't sound right here. "tab dividers for columns and ; for cells". Columns == Cells in CSV.

Comment: I believe that your issue is with the delimiters. if you have control of the generation of the file i recommend using another character that will not exist in your cell data like maybe the pipe character ( | )

Comment: No, the file is parsed from another site affect its completion, I can not.
the question is how to parse this file, gathering all the strings in the array if a separator is used in the cell, which also occurs in, but is framed by ""

Comment: There's not a single tab in the CSV sample you show us; it's clearly semicolon-delimited. The output you get is actually correct, given you're telling `fgetcsv` to look for `\t` for some reason.

Comment: I did so. This file uses the semicolon, tabs, and semicolons within double quotes. so just specify the tab does not work. and use the semicolon separator, I can not, because parser then takes into account those who are inside the quotes.